# Java seperate method to find Prime numbers

Tags: java, methods, primes

I have written a program to find whether a number is prime or not.

The program has 2 methods:

1. take input from user as to the numbers(stored in an array)
2. take each element of the array and to find whether it is prime or not (this method return type is `boolean`)

Now my 2<sup>nd</sup> method is always returning true for all values.

```
public static boolean Isprime(int x){

    boolean isprime = false;

    for(int m=2;m<x/2;m++){

        int temp = x%m;
        if(temp == 0){
            isprime = false;
        }
        else{
            isprime = true;
        }
    }
    return isprime;
}
```

Edited:

```
public static  boolean Isprime(int x){

    boolean isprime = false;

    for(int m=2;m<=x/2;m++){

        int temp = x%m;
        if(temp == 0){
            isprime = false;
            break;
        }
        else{
            isprime = true; 
        }
    }
    return isprime;
}
```

P.S - It is working for 9 as well.

Comment: and so what seems to be the trouble young man?

Comment: Am terribly sorry i jst solved the issue.. 
the trouble previously was that for every integer of multiple of 5 it was returning true.. 
jst nided to put a break; inside the If statement.. 

i always do get answers after posting my problems here,even from myself :)
Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Did you try pretending to be the computer? Say you pass `9`, then it checks if `9%2==0`, which it isn't, so it sets `isprime` to true. Then it checks if `9%3==0`, which it is, so it sets `isprime` to false. Then it checks if `9%4==0`, which it isn't, so it sets `isprime` to true. Then it returns `isprime`, which is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break out of for loop as soon as you found if it is not a prime and slighlty modified approach you can follow to omit some code and optimize it as well.

```
  public static  boolean Isprime(int x){
    boolean isprime = true;

    for(int m=2;m<=Math.sqrt(x);m++){

        int temp = x%m;
        if(temp == 0){
            isprime = false;
            break;
            }
      }
    return isprime;

  }
```

Comment: another small question.. in my full program i've mentioned an IF 


statement inside the main method 


<tag>
for(int a=0;a<saheb.length;a++){
    int number = saheb[a];
   
   if(Isprime(number)){
    System.out.println(number+" is prime");
   }
   
   }
</tag>
Now whenever it finds a prime it is giving me the number printed as"is prime" now i want to add an else statement which will give a print"no prime found" if der is no.. but if i add it inside the For loop then the loop doesnt go on.. (increment stops in its first run) what can i do?

Comment: what you need to do is to use a boolean and assign it as false before for loop. In your if (prime) check make it true. after the for loop just check the value of boolean if it is still false then there was no prime found.

Comment: @ Sanjeev, your code wont work all the time. Check it for 49 as a number. FYI, 49 is non-prime

Comment: @Aditya why do you think so ? try it.

Comment: so i need to take a boolean value and add another IF statement for the printing of "no prime found" i was hoping there would be a easier way to do, b'coz taking so many IF and FOR loop increases the complexity

Comment: @Sanjeev You were missing the equal condition in if Condition, now it will work. Try posting the code which is not erroneous

Comment: @user3291928 thats the easiest way to achieve what you want.

Comment: hmm yup its not working.. 
But the dilemma remains.. 
What do i need to do ?

Comment: @user3291928 Add the information required further in the question instead of chat. And first acceot the answer and then you can ask next question

Comment: OKies.. solved it.. Hope the code works now.. Posting it

Comment: public static  boolean Isprime(int x){
 
 
  
   boolean isprime = false;
   
   for(int m=2;m<=x/2;m++){
    
    int temp = x%m;
    if(temp == 0){
     isprime = false;
     break;
     }
    else{
     isprime = true;
    
   
    }
    }
   return isprime;
   
  
  
 }

Comment: Not here, in your main for loop which is calling this function that you posted in an earlier comment

Comment: @aditya Sorry, i'm new here so i dont know about the rules..
Thanks for the help

Comment: @user3291928 There is no need to make isPrime = true in else block, it is true anyways

Comment: @aditya i initialized the isprime = false, so i think i need to make it true in else block